# mysql join query from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

i want to the join query from three table 1 tbl_customerinfo , 2 tbl_customerinfo ,3- tbl_cust_ext_pref;

i want add to table 3( tbl_cust_ext_pref ) in this query ..

i have using join query from two table and get all informations and code is working a- tbl_customerinfo feild name ( id ,c_shortcode, c_type)

b - tbl_cust_extinfo

feild name ( cx_id ,cx_gender,cs_createdby)

i have use this code

/* code here */

```
$this->db->select ( this is a table

                  'tbl_customerinfo.c_id,
                  tbl_customerinfo.c_shortcode,
                   tbl_customerinfo.c_type,

/*this is b table tbl_cust_extinfo.cx_id, tbl_cust_extinfo.cx_gender, tbl_cust_extinfo.cs_createdby*/

                     ');

           $this->db->from('tbl_customerinfo');
       $this->db->join
       (
        'tbl_cust_extinfo', 
        'tbl_customerinfo.c_id = tbl_cust_extinfo.cx_id'

        );

        $query = $this->db->get();
//$info='tbl_customerinfo';
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        //print_r($row);
        //exit();


        $info[] = array(
                         'c_id' => $row->c_id,
                         'c_shortcode' => $row->c_shortcode,
                         'c_type'=> $row->c_type


                         array(

                                 'cx_id'=> $row-> cx_id,
                                 'cx_gender'=> $row -> cx_gender);
```

Comment: What is the problem specifically? Where is the rest of code? What does it even do?

Comment: i want to one more table join this query this table name is  tbl_cust_ext_pref an field name cid ,mid and xven

Comment: At least mention table columns. Why do you need to join 3 tables?

Comment: i want to one more table join this query this table name is  tbl_cust_ext_pref an field name cid ,mid and xven

Answer (score 0):

Write your sql query once in a single query:

```
$sql = 'select * from table1 join table2 on table1.c1 = table2.c2 '
        . 'join table3 on table1.c1 = table3.c3';
$res = mysql_query($sql);
```